# MySQL and Django, syncdb not syncing

Tags: mysql, windows, python-2.7

I keep getting the classic `1045, "Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"` error. The edited part of settings.py looks like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'user', 
        'PASSWORD': '*******', 
        'HOST': 'localhost', 
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

I have also tried doing `'HOST': '127.0.0.1'` . The password is the same as what you enter when starting the server through Notifier and checking the its status in Workbench, correct?

UPDATE: this thread basically lead to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002593/mysql-not-connecting-in-cmd), where the kinks get worked out.

Comment: Test it on the command-line, run `mysql -u user -p`.

Comment: @alecxe `'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`