# MySQL not connecting in cmd

Tags: mysql

I keep getting the error 1045(28000) when trying the `mysql -u user -p` command. The same password works in the MySQL Command Line Client and the server is running according to Workbench and Notifier. Not sure if this is related, but the only odd thing is that Notifier shows that I have two things running, both named "MySQL56_1" and when I try to stop the one where I don't have the option to "Configure Instance" or open the "SQL Editor", I get the error saying that it was "not found in the Windows Services".

EDIT: still have not solved this, all of the commands mentioned here yield error 1045 with the variations of mentioning either 'user'@'localhost' or 'ODBC'@'localhost'

Comment: Try connecting by IP address: `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u user -p`

Comment: @TajMorton same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if anyone is interested, here what worked for me. In Workbench, on the bottom left hand corner, there will be all these "schemas" listed, click on any one (they all show the same parameters in my case at least) and, using all the relevant parameters specified under Information>Session, play around with the commands listed in [this chapter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html) . Basically what user Aman Aggarwal was talking about, just took me a while to understand how this cross checking is done exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The error 1045(28000)   denoted for Access Denied to the user..

You are using different connection parameters in sql editor and cmd..

Cross check your username, password, socket file path, hostname and reconnect via cmd.

Thanks

Comment: @AmanAggrawal sorry, I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by cross check? I can look up all of those parameters in the editor, but what do I cross check them with and how?